# FM radio for the ipad?

Tags: iphone, ipad

ok this is just strickly out of curiosity here because i have read some articles talking about the a4 & a5 chips in the ipad and iphone can pick up FM signals. Does anyone know if there is an actual "FM RADIO" app out that doesnt require wifi or 3g?

I ask because at some point im going to put the new ipad in my truck and this would determin if i actually leave a radio in there as well or just have the ipad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the iPad 2 does have the [Broadcom BCM4329 - Low-Power 802.11n with Bluetooth® 2.1 + EDR and FM (Tx and Rx)](http://www.broadcom.com/products/Bluetooth/Bluetooth-RF-Silicon-and-Software-Solutions/BCM4329) chip, but third-party apps do not have low-level access to it.